# Can we modify the div once component renders in react?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to find a solution to modify the height of the div for react based on how many elements it will consist to grow automatically.

So, to do the same i have chosen jquery

```
     ul.each(function() {
        const self = $(this);
        const { listCount, ulCount } = getListItemsCount(self);
        const ruleHeight = listCount * listDefaultHeight;
        const children = $(self).children();

        /* Swapping of elements to adjust the heights */
        if (children.length - 1 === 2 && ulCount === 1) {
          if ($(children[2]).data('count') > $(children[1]).data('count')) {
            $($(self).children()[2]).insertBefore($($(self).children()[1]));
            //ruleHeight += 25;
          }
        }

        $(self)
          .find('div')
          .css({ height: `${ruleHeight}px` });
      });
```

The above code is happening inside `componentDidMount()`. The reason I am doing here, we are not sure how much height we need to increase as the div position is absolute and also depending upon the first level content, we are swapping the divs as well as a high-level overview.

[image]

The blue and ping is an absolute div whose height is growing accordingly, if the first level data is less and second level has nested and more list items, the height was not adjusting, so swapping the divs and its working.

The question here is: Is it the right approach to handle this with jquery?
React DOM is not updated now? How to update the react dom as well, if suppose render method is called, will the jquery code is written become obsolete?

Is there a possibility to adjust the height using flex automatically without using jquery for absolute positions or by just css will be awesome fix?

Please guide the best practice to do the same

Comment: The (99%) right approach is to not use jQuery to modify your DOM when using React.  If you are using react to build your views, **use it**.

Comment: I understand, i did not find any solutions and hence used it for time being, updated my question to check if there is any alternative solutions to the problems what i am facing

Comment: step 1: stop using jquery, and then step 2: write the sizing logic into the react component, setting appropriate CSS classes based on what you know about the content. The important part is to immediately stop using jQuery, because using React means React owns the UI: it's not browser content, it's React content that happens to use the browser to render itself. Consider the DOM it generates off limits: it is off limits, don't try to touch it. If you need to change how it renders, then make React do that based on _its_ code.

Comment: I agree and hence posting to find an right solution here, by any chance we can handle this with css and flex only ???

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest do not use jquery instead , write  a function to calculate height of the div in componentDidMount and set the height of the div in render method.

Here is an example

```
componentWillMount() {

       this.setDivHeight();
  }


return () {

       render(
          <div style={{height: this.state.divHeight}}>

          </div>
        )
  }
```

This just for reference, you have to call a function to set change value of state divHeight to re render the component and the div height will also change on each render. Also  would suggest user in JSX to code your components. Tips about [JSX](https://flaviocopes.com/jsx/#css-in-react)

Comment: I liked ur idea but it will not fit with my requirement as I dono how many divs I’ll have to update as it’s inside a recursive function